# Работа с объектами в calabash-cucumber

Tags: android, ios, ruby, test-automation, cucumber

Здравствуйте, сообщество!

В процессе изучения calabash-cucumber для тестирования мобильных приложений возник вопрос как работать с объектами. Для тестирования взял приложение iOS, и вот на одном из Активити есть 4 вопроса и 3 ответа на каждый вопрос. Для прохождения на следующее Активити нужно ответь на эти вопросы, а ответ это отметка варианта напротив вопроса. Рисунок примерно такой получается:

```
 |1|0|0| или |1|0|0|
 |0|1|0| или |1|0|0|
 |0|0|1| или |1|0|0|
 |1|0|0| или |0|0|1|
```

1 - выбранный вариант (чек-бокс); 0 - соответсвенно не выбранное поле. 
Привязки к кнопке нет - ни ID, ни текста. Приходится находить ее по координатам. И вот вопрос: как задать объект(кнопка) с заданными координатами, а потом передавать ему метод (например object.touch(x, y)) в теле шага. Возник интерес проверить все комбинации, а их 81(в шагах это очень много) - с объектами было бы легче(можно счетчик для перебора написать). Вот мои попытки, но они не работают:

```
class Tapper
    def tap(x, y)
        perform_action('click_on_screen', x, y)
        #or touch(nil, {:offset => {:x => x.to_i, :y => y.to_i}})
    end
end
```

```
Then /^I touch on screen $/ do |x, y|
  @answer_1_1 = Tapper.new
  @answer_1_1.tap(802, 153)
end
```

Результат или: `undefined step`, либо `undefined method 'perform_action' for Object`

Comment: А почему @answer_1_1.perform_action(802, 153), а не @answer_1_1.tap(802, 153) ? У вас же в классе Tapper метод tap определен? Кроме того, у вас в начале вопроса матрица, вы не хотите создать матрицу при помощи массива массивов, чтобы вместо @answer_1_1 использовать @answer[0][0]? Было бы гораздо удобнее обходить чекбоксы во вложенных циклах/итераторах.

Comment: @cheops Метод исправил - опечатка в вопросе.  Я думал о вложенных массивах, но пока не получается создать объект не пробовал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calabash x-platform позволяет работать с объектами и классами.
https://github.com/calabash/x-platform-example